# Simplify series of finite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to have a closed form or any nicer form for the following series:

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\,\frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma (m+2)}\left(\frac{R}{2}\right)^{2m+1}\,x^{m}\sum_{j=1}^m\frac{(j-1)!}{(ax)^j}$$

or

$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\,\frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma (m+2)}\left(\frac{R}{2}\right)^{2m+1}\,x^{m+1}\sum_{j=1}^{m+1}\frac{(j-1)!}{(ax)^j}$$

with $R,a>0$.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one needs to simplify 
$$\Sigma=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\,\frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma (m+2)}\left(\frac{R}{2}\right)^{2m+1}\,x^{m+1}\sum_{j=1}^{m+1}\frac{(j-1)!}{(ax)^j}$$
First let's assume the inner sum:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{m+1}\frac{(j-1)!}{(ax)^j}=\frac{1}{a x}\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{n!}{(ax)^n}=-(-1)^m (m+1)! e^{-a x} \Gamma (-m-1,-a x)-e^{-a x} \Gamma (0,-a x)$$
where $\Gamma (\cdot,\cdot)$ - is [the incomplete Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).
So the series will split in to so series $\Sigma=\Sigma_1+\Sigma_2$:
$$\Sigma_1=-\frac{xR}{2}e^{-ax}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\,\frac{\left(\frac{R^2x}{4}\right)^{m}}{m!}\,\Gamma (-m-1,-a x) \\
\Sigma_2=-\frac{xR}{2}e^{-a x} \Gamma (0,-a x)\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\,\frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma (m+2)}\left(\frac{R^2x}{4}\right)^{m}$$
Making the summation one gets:
$$\Sigma_2=-\frac{xR}{2}e^{-a x} \Gamma (0,-a x)\frac{J_1\left(2\sqrt{\frac{R^2x}{4}}\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{R^2x}{4}}}=-\sqrt{x}J_1(R\sqrt{x})e^{-a x} \Gamma (0,-a x)$$
The computation of the first series is not that straightforward. 

 One can leave it like this:
$$\Sigma=-\frac{xR}{2}e^{-ax}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\,\frac{\left(\frac{R^2x}{4}\right)^{m}}{m!}\,\Gamma (-m-1,-a x)-\sqrt{x}J_1(R\sqrt{x})e^{-a x} \Gamma (0,-a x)$$
Or use the integral representation of [$\Gamma (\cdot,\cdot)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.6.E4) (I'll skip this step):
$$\Sigma_1=\frac{R}{2a}\int_0^{\infty } \frac{t e^{-t}}{t-a x} \, \mathrm dt \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\,\frac{(-1)^m\left(\frac{R^2t}{4a}\right)^{m}}{m!\Gamma (m)}=-\frac{R^2}{4a^{\frac{3}{2}}}\int_0^{\infty }\frac{t \ J_1\left(\frac{R }{\sqrt{a}}\sqrt{t}\right)e^{-t}}{t-a x} \, \mathrm dt $$
And the last integral can be computed numerically or you can look through tables of integral of special function like *Gradshteyn I.S., Ryzhik I.M. Tables of Integrals, Series, and Products*.

Comment: Thanks..the final step you show is for $\Sigma$ and not $\Sigma_2$, right?

Comment: Ah.. yes, it should be $\Sigma_1$. I've corrected it.